# Configuring Apache as reverse proxy to Tomcat using https

Tags: apache, ssl, https, proxy, tomcat7

I want to configure apache as reverse proxy using SSL, I can't make it work.
In my SSL configuration file:

```
  ProxyRequests off 
  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass /examples http://host.ex.org:8080/examples
  ProxyPassReverse /examples http://host.ex.org:8080/examples
  ProxyPass /examples https://host.ex.org:8443/examples2
  ProxyPassReverse /examples https://host.ex.org:8443/examples2

  SSLCertificateFile    /path/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/server.key
  SSLCACertificateFile  /path/ca.crt
  SSLProxyCACertificateFile "/path/tomcat_ca.crt"
```

On Tomcat's server.xml file I have configured the connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200"
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
    keystoreFile="/path/tomcat.ks" keystorePass="***"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I have enabled ssl, proxy and cache modules. It works with http but it doesn't with https.
Logs tell me SSL is correctly configured, but connecting to https://localhost/examples2 I have the following error:

```
ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert
```

It let me think it is a certificate problem, but both apache2 and tomcat7 work with their certificate with https.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I had to comment
      SSLVerifyClient require
      SSLVerifyDepth 10

directives for the client side authentication.